# How would a two input XOR gate behave when it's two inputs are shorted?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

I know that for a NAND and NOR gate, the resulting gate now acts as a NOT gate. But I'm confused on how it will act for XOR.

Comment: Interesting question. While similar questions could be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here (especially within a programming context), this question is more likely to have an answer on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `XOR(x, x) = 0`; so it would be always constant `0`. At least as a logical perspective.